# Adding a decimal point to each element in a column of numbers

Tags: unix

I have a file like so:

```
abc 123456 566671 487823 244211 911234 778234 671123 455321
fgd 1567988 2556118 4798739 1803812 9208018 4712324 2134981 1027431
etc..
```

I want to add a decimal point 3 digits from the right to every number. So if I have 123456, I should get 123.456 and if i have 1234567, I should get 1234.567.

First, I added zeros to the end of every 6 digit number( my file has numbers with minimum 6 digits) and executed the `sed` commands below:

`sed 's/.\{8\}/& /g' | sed 's/ \./ /g'`

My expected:

```
abc 123.456 566.671 487.823 244.211 911.234 778.234 671.123 455.321
fgd 1567.988 2556.118 4798.739 1803.812 9208.018 4712.324 2134.981 1027.431
```

My actual:

```
abc 1234.560 5666.710 4878.230 2442.110 9112.340 7782.340 6711.230 4553.210
fgd 1567.988 2556.118 4798.739 1803.812 9208.018 4712.324 2134.981 1027.431
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My pick is to open the file in Vim and do a search-and-replace with this:

`:%s/\([0-9]\{3}\)\( \|$\)/.\1\2/gc`

or do it the`sed` way:

`$ sed 's/\([0-9]\{3\}\)\( \|$\)/.\1\2/g' input.txt`

Comment: yup, works, took me some time to figure out that while applying your regular expression to sed(before your edit), we need to add a \ at `\{3}\`. thanks

Comment: @RohithPrasadKM Welcome. Had to take a look at section 5.3 here https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.pdf , since `sed` isn't my daily tool.

Comment: Thank you for sharing! Appreciate it!